# Matlab - ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix, dimension

I have the following code (part of a larger program) in `matlab`:

```
while(k<n)
C.(sprintf('Cnew')) = C.(sprintf('C%d',k));
d1 = equalize_dimension(a.F, C.(sprintf('Cnew')));
distance_new = distance(d1.x, d1.y);
k = k + 1;
end
```

If you want to substitute values since I have included part of the program, this would be as follows:

```
C.(sprintf('Cnew')):
```

78

And, for `a.F` it is as follows:

78    82    84    80

80    84    86    82

82    87    88    85

82    87    89    86

For the `equalize_dimension(x,y)` function, it is as follows:

```
function n = equalize_dimension (x,y)
        [r1 c1] = size(x);
        [r2 c2] = size(y);

        if r1<r2
        e= r2-r1;
        for i=1:e
        x(r1+1,1)=0;
        r1 = r1 + 1;
        end
        [r1 c1] = size(x);
        n.x =x;
        n.y = y;
        end

        if r1>r2
        e = r1-r2;
        for i=1:e
        y(r2+1,1)=0;
        r2 = r2 + 1;
        end
        [r2 c2] = size(y);
        n.x = x;
        n.y = y;
        end

        if c1<c2
        e= c2-c1;
        for i=1:e
        x(1,c1+1)=0;
        c1 = c1 + 1;
        end
        [r1 c1] = size(x);
        n.x = x;
        n.y = y;
        end

        if c1>c2
        e = c1-c2;
        for i=1:e
        y(1,c2+1)=0;
        c2 = c2 + 1;
        end
        [r2 c2] = size(y);
        n.x = x;
        n.y = y;
        end

        if r1==r2 && c1==c2
        n.x =  x;
        n.y = y;
        end
```

And, for the `distance(x,y)` function, it is as follows:

```
function m = distance(x,y)
[r c] = size(x);
for i=1:r
     for j=1:c
     summation = (sum(sum(pdist2(x,y))));
     end
end
     m=summation;
end
```

When I run the program, I get the following error:

```
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> fs at 36
distance_new = distance(d1.x, d1.y);
```

Why is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, stop in debugger before line `distance_new = distance(d1.x, d1.y);`
and type

```
>> which distance
```

I suspect that you'll get as output

> distance is a variable.

Meaning that you override the function `distance` by using a variable with the same name.

Second, in function `distance` what is the reason for the nested loop on `i` and `j`? You are not using these variables and `summation` is computed regardless of the nested loops.
please also try [not to use `i` and `j` as variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).